# Reading a segment register (%gs) which contains the pointer to a list

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, cpu-registers, memory-segmentation

I have stumbled upon this kernel page: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/x86/x86_64/fsgs.html and wanted to play around with `LD_PRELOAD` to see whether I can allocate a value at a load-time and read the segment register at runtime to load the value.

For example, I have two simple codes that can be easily compiled and executed to demonstrate (I had to modify a bit from example code provided in the kernel site):

`load.c` compiled with `gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o load.so load.c -ldl -mfsgsbase`

```
#include <sys/auxv.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
/* Will be eventually in asm/hwcap.h */
#ifndef HWCAP2_FSGSBASE
#define HWCAP2_FSGSBASE        (1 << 1)
#endif
#define _GNU_SOURCE
void __attribute__((constructor)) load()
{
    int a = 4;
    unsigned val = getauxval(AT_HWCAP2);
    if (val & HWCAP2_FSGSBASE)
        printf("FSGSBASE enabled\n");

    int *addr_a = mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);     
    if (addr_a == MAP_FAILED) {     
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed\n");     
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    *addr_a = a;
    _writegsbase_u64(addr_a);
}
```

and

`main.c` compiled with `gcc -S main.c -o main.s && sed -i 's/-4(%rbp)/%gs:0x0/g' main.s && gcc main.s -o main`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;  
    printf("From main: %d\n", a);
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Upon executing the command: `> LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/load.so ./main`

```
FSGSBASE enabled
From main: 4
Hello World!
```

So now I can successfully load the value at runtime (`sed` modifies the assembly code to read `%gs` register as instructed in the kernel page)

---

**Next, I wanted to do something more interesting: store the base address of a list in the segment register `%gs` and access this address at runtime.**

For instance, I modified the above `load` code like this (I just added two lines, but for the sake of completeness):

`load_updated.c` compiled with `gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o load_updated.so load_updated.c -ldl -mfsgsbase`

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) load()
{
    int a = 4;
    unsigned val = getauxval(AT_HWCAP2);
    if (val & HWCAP2_FSGSBASE)
        printf("FSGSBASE enabled\n");

    int *addr_a = mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);     
    if (addr_a == MAP_FAILED) {     
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed\n");     
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    *addr_a = a;
    int *table[] = {addr_a};
    printf("Table base address: %p\n", &table);
    _writegsbase_u64(&table);
}
```

However, loading the pointer address to a list to the segment register is not the same as loading the value (my first example). Therefore, I wanted to know how I should approach solving this problem of trying to read a segment register that contains the pointer to a list.

I have attempted to debug this by executing it with `gdb` like the following:

```
gdb ./main
pwndbg> set environment LD_PRELOAD ./load_updated.so
pwndbg> b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1171
pwndbg> start
FSGSBASE enabled
Table base address: 0x7fffffffd880 0x7ffff7fb5000
pwndbg> i r $gs_base
gs_base        0x7fffffffd880      140737488345216
```

So I can check that I did indeed load the correct pointer address to the `%gs` register. Then when I step into

```
   0x555555555171 <main+8>     sub    rsp, 0x10
 ► 0x555555555175 <main+12>    mov    eax, dword ptr gs:[0]
   0x55555555517d <main+20>    mov    esi, eax
```

The instruction where I am trying to dereference the value of `%gs` into the `%eax` register, `%eax` register is loaded with nothing:

```
pwndbg> i r eax
rax            0x0                 0
```

I have also tried to simply `mov` the value from the `%gs` register into the `%eax` register (no dereferencing) by manually modifying the assembly code of
`movl   %gs:0, %eax` -> `movl %gs, %eax`

But to no avail, and now I'm wondering whether there might be some other assembly codes I may need to add and trying to get some clue on how to go from this.

I thought this might be interesting because if I can obtain the base address of a list at runtime, I could most likely use pointer arithmetic to access different elements of the list allocated at load time.

FWIW here is my OS information and architecture:

```
> uname -a
Linux pop-os 6.2.6-76060206-generic #202303130630~1685473338~22.04~995127e SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue M x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I appreciate any insights, and please let me know if I'm unclear in any parts of my question.

---

Edit: Thanks to @Peter Cordes; I figured out that you can instead add the assembly instruction of:

```
    rdgsbase %rax
    movq    0x0(%rax), %rax
```

To answer the question.

The warning is that although you can read the `%gs` register this way, for unknown reasons, the address stored in the register doesn't contain the array (so that's another thing to figure out).

Just for completeness, what I mean is that if I were to run the gdb similar to the above, it would look like this:

```
pwndbg> set environment LD_PRELOAD ./load.so
pwndbg> b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1171
pwndbg> start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x1171
Table addr: (base address) 0x7fffffffd870 (*table[0]) 0x7ffff7ffa000
```

it looks like this in GDB:

```
*RAX  0x7fffffffd870 ◂— 0x86d11c8e53b3e43
──────────────────────────────────────────[ DISASM / x86-64 / set emulate on ]──────────────────────────────────────────
   0x555555555171 <main+8>     sub    rsp, 0x10
   0x555555555175 <main+12>    rdgsbase rax
 ► 0x55555555517a <main+17>    mov    rax, qword ptr [rax + 0x40]
```

As it can be observed, `0x7fffffffd870` doesn't contain `0x7ffff7ffa000` as expected, but some garbage value of `0x86d11c8e53b3e43`.

Comment: `movl %gs, %eax` reads the 16-bit selector value (index into the GDT), zero-extended to 32-bit. (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).  You're not in real mode so that's unrelated to the segment base, and a 64-bit kernel will just use a null selector (`0`) for ds/es/fs/gs, only setting up segment descriptors for CS and SS which x86-64 still requires to keep the machine happy (and tell it that it's in 64-bit long mode).  You need `rdgsbase` or a system call (since the other way, reading an MSR, isn't available in user-space.)

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes; your suggestion worked as I expected it to. I will edit the question and add what I did to adhere to your suggestion. I realized that for some reason, I am still unable to load the table from the main application, but since that's outside of the scope of this question I'll keep trying to figure it out. Thank you again!

Comment: You can (and should) post answers as proper answers, not edits to the question.  (That's what the "answer your own question" button is for.)  Or I guess I can just post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you could do that, please do so, and I will accept it; I didn't want to take credit for something that is not my answer (and just wanted to post an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`movl %gs, %eax` reads the 16-bit selector value (index into the GDT), zero-extended to 32-bit. (https://felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).

You're not in real mode so that's unrelated to the segment base, and a 64-bit kernel will just use a null selector (0) for `ds`/`es`/`fs`/`gs`, only setting up segment descriptors for CS and SS which x86-64 still requires to keep the machine happy (and tell it that it's in 64-bit long mode).

**You need [`rdgsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdfsbase:rdgsbase) or a system call (since reading an MSR is a privileged operation, not available directly in user-space.)**  In 64-bit mode, the mechanism for setting a 64-bit segment base for FS or GS is by writing MSRs, rather than creating a GDT or LDT entry and doing `mov %eax, %gs`.  (In 64-bit mode, other segment bases are fixed at 0.)

My answer on [How to access segment register without linking libc.so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65468487/how-to-access-segment-register-without-linking-libc-so) shows how to write FS with a Linux `arch_prctl` system call, which was the only option on CPUs without the FSGSBASE extension and a kernel that enabled it for use by user-space.  (The latter being much more recently than the first silicon to support `wrfsbase` / `rdfsbase` etc.)  The same syscall with different args could read a segment base.