# Finding the memory address of fs:28h

Tags: c, linux, gdb, x86-64, memory-segmentation

I debug a program with gdb for fun, with stack guard so it writes the canary to the stack from fs:28h. Out of curiosity, I trying to find the memory address that fs:28h points to.
I encounter two problems. first, gdb cannot show me the value in gdtr/ldtr because it doesn't run in ring zero. second, When reading fs with gdb it contains 0, how does it make sense? I know that gdt/ldt contain 0 in the first index to return invalid address and the RPL is off so what am I missing here? If anyone knows how to find the address that segment register fs points to I would like to know.

```
file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked
```

Comment: The segment register *value* is the null selector.  The segment base is set separately, via an MSR or `wrfsbase` in 64-bit mode.  Related: [Reading a segment register (%gs) which contains the pointer to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76645203)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `x86_64-linux-gnu`, i.e. all three of x86-64 CPU, Linux kernel, and the GNU C Library.  With this combination of hardware and system software, the FS segment is set such that the memory operand `%fs:0` refers to the beginning of the *thread control block* for the currently executing thread.  (A thread control block is an internal C library data structure that describes a running thread.  You can think of it as the object referred to by a `pthread_t` thread handle.)

Precisely because x86 has historically not made it easy for unprivileged code to look up the "actual" address (more precisely "linear virtual address") referred to by a `%fs:xxx` or `%gs:xxx` memory operand, [the first field of the thread control block on `x86_64-linux-gnu` is a pointer to the thread control block itself](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/tls.h;h=1403f939f7e5a81aeabf58aefac011dd3ce14de6;hb=bb9a4fc02841cf58a112a44b259477547893838b#l142).  Thus,

```
void *read_fs(void) {
    void *rv;
    asm("movq %%fs:0, %0" : "=r" (rv));
    return rv;
}
```

will return the address you want.  Keep in mind that this is *only* guaranteed to be true on `x86_64-linux-gnu`.  If you switch to a different Unix kernel (e.g. FreeBSD) or a different C library (e.g. musl libc), there's a good chance that the FS segment will still point to the thread control block, but the data in that space is likely to be rather different.

Comment: 1. nope, the "effective address" is the offset part of a `seg:off` logical address.  Segment overrides have no effect on LEA.  (Remember the original 8086 use-case was for address math to generate pointers (near pointers = offsets) that could be dereferenced with the existing segment base.  If LEA added the segment base, first of all it would be a 20-bit linear address which might not fit in a 16-bit 8086 register, and dereferencing the pointer would add the segment base again.)

Comment: To read a segment base from user-space, you need `rdfsbase` on a CPU + kernel that support it.  (Linux kernel 5.9, and Ivy Bridge or later Intel IIRC.)  See [Reading a segment register (%gs) which contains the pointer to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76645203) / [How to access segment register without linking libc.so?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65468487)

Comment: @PeterCordes Now that I'm on a real computer, I have rewritten my answer so that it should be accurate for x86-64+Linux+glibc regardless of the availability of `rdfsbase`.